# Loop not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I run the program it ends up averages it out but it wont loop! Does anyone see what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> using namespace std;

//function prototypes 

void getTestScores(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3); 
double calcAverage(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3); 
void displayAverage(double avg);

int main() 
{   
    //declare variables
    double score1 = 0.0; 
    double score2 =0.0;     
    double score3 = 0.0; 
    double avg    = 0.0;

    //display average in fixed-point notation   
    getTestScores(score1,score2,score3);    
    calcAverage(avg);
    displayAverage(avg); 

    //enter scores
    while (avg != -1 ); 
    {
        cout << "score 1 (negative number to stop): ";
        cin >> score1;
        cout << "Enter score 2(negative number to stop): ";
        cin >> score2;
        cout << "Enter score 3(negative number to stop): ";
        cin >> score3;

        calcAverage(score1, score2, score3);
        displayAverage(avg); 

        return 0;
    }
} //end of main function

//*****function prototypes***** 
void getTestScores(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3) 
{
   cout << "Enter score 1(negative numberto stop): ";
   cin >> score1;
   cout << "Enter score 2(negative number to stop): ";
   cin >> score2;
   cout << "Enter score 3(negative number to stop): ";
   cin >> score3;
}  //end

double calcAverage (double &score1, double &score2, double &score3)
{
    double average = 0.0; 
    average = calcAverage(score1, score2, score3);

    return average;
} //end of clacAverage

void displayAverage(double avg)     
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
    cout << "Average: " << avg << endl;
} //end
```

Comment: Use 4 spaces before each code statement or just select the entire code and click `{}` present on the editor tab.

Comment: how come you want three parameters in `calcAverage` like this `double calcAverage(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3);` but giving one parameter like this `calcAverage(avg);` ? I am not a c++ boy i am sorry if what i ask is noob.Also I think you should remove the `;` after `while(avg!=-1)`

Comment: about (avg != -1): don't directly compare floating point numbers (see http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_compare_floating_point_numbers_in_the_C_programming_language)

Comment: Emre the reason why I declared them was because the two voids had to match! And when i defined the functions prototypes: if i only declared avg. and calculated the scores there was erros

Answer (score 7):

There is a semicolon after your `while()` loop. Try removing it.

Answer (score 4):

You have `return` in you `while` block. Return stops everything, including loops. Only Python (AFAIK) allows to put return in cycle and get it cycling.

Answer (score 0):

@Katie: Does your code even compile? Your calcAverage(avg); function call is different from how you have defined it. Did you forget to add code for an overloaded function with the (same name) signature calcAverage(double )???

BTW, remove the semicolon after the while() and it might run fine. Try this after you check my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Return will end the loop and return control back  to where the function is called..
Also it doesn't seem like you re initialize avg again in the loop body? you return the avg but do not store it 
should be

```
avg = calcaAverage(1,2,3)
```